# Trouble getting a list of the client names from GUI and sending to server

Tags: java, arraylist, server, client, kryonet

I'm working on a multiplayer/client game using kryonet and JAVAFX for the GUI.
I'm having trouble simply getting a the names of clients after they connect to the server. I thought of getting the name from the TextField and adding it to my ArrayLIst when the connect button is clicked.

Problem is that whenever the button is clicked, the name is added to the list but it's the only one, it seems as though I am creating a new list. What am I doing wrong? I'd like to pass the list on to the server and/or create an observable list for the GUI. Is there a better way of doing this? I just need a list from the "clientNameText"-TextField. I hope I have supplied enough code.

Thanks in advance!

Server code when a client joins, getting ID is working fine

```
public class ServerController {

 List<String> clients = new ArrayList();

// this is the method I call in the GUI
  public String addName(String name) {
    clients.add(name);
    return name;
 }
public void connected(Connection connection) {
        if (connection instanceof Connection) {
            clientMap.put(connection.getID(), connection.toString());
            System.out.println("Map: " + clientMap.toString());
            //clients.add("Player " + connection.getID());
            System.out.println(clients);
            //lobby.addPlayer(connection.getID());
            //user.addID(connection.getID());
        }
    }
```

sets the button in GUI class to action:

```
    TextField clientNameText = new TextField("Username");
    Button clientToGame = new Button("Connect");
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

    clientToGame.setOnAction((ActionEvent w) -> {
        clientController.connect();
        // this always adds the last client who joint but the rest are delted
        serverController.addName(clientNameText.getText());
        obsList.addAll(serverController.getClientList());
        window.setScene(lobbyScene);
    }
    );
```